# What is the ideal technique to protect unauthorized redirects

Tags: web-application, appsec, url-redirection

I'm looking for the best way to secure unauthorized redirects from GET parameter where

```
url=http://example.com
```

I'm thinking about creating an unique identifier like using a hashing function (md5 for example) and check whether `hash(url) === passed hash` via GET to validate the redirect or deny it,

Where passed hash is within an html tag like: `<a href="?url=url_here&hash=pre_calculated_here">` And I think this is bad because an attacker can figure it out, maybe add an unique `HASH_SUFFIX` by applying md5 to `url+hash_suffix`

What is the best way to protect my redirects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one domain you can usually get away with simply prefixing a safe url (should have) `handler`://`host`/ (<--- the final slash is important).

```
redirect("https://example.com/"+$url);
```

Or you could whitelist all the known domain prefixes and compare the url to the whitelist (again safe url rules from above applies).

If you're planning on precalculating all the hashes of the redirect urls I presume you know all urls and you could just make a lookup table:

```
if ($url=="0000") {
  redirect("https://example.com");
} elseif ($url == "0001") {
  redirect("https://otherplace.com");
}
```

A whitelist will always be more effective than obscuring the redirect. Adding a prefix or suffix to the url before hashing can still be bruteforced just like a password hash can be, just consider the url a salt, but its unlikely that any attacker would go through that much effort. Open redirects by themselves are not significantly more dangerous than users clicking on links in email.